# Pick up the latest releases from each major node version with jq

Tags: json, shell, grouping, jq

Are there any smart ways to pick up the latest releases from each major  node version with `jq`? Or do I have to write another wrapper shell script to handle its output?

What I want to get (there are three major versions: v8, v9 and v10) the latest versions:

```
v10.1.0
v9.11.1
v8.11.2
```

The release list:

```
$ export repo='nodejs/node'
$ curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/${repo}/tags |jq -r ".[].name"
v10.1.0
v10.0.0
v9.11.1
v9.11.0
v9.10.1
v9.10.0
v9.9.0
v9.8.0
v9.7.1
v9.7.0
v9.6.1
v9.6.0
v9.5.0
v9.4.0
v9.3.0
v9.2.1
v9.2.0
v9.1.0
v9.0.0
v8.11.2
v8.11.1
v8.11.0
v8.10.0
v8.9.4
v8.9.3
v8.9.2
v8.9.1
v8.9.0
v8.8.1
v8.8.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pipe the output of curl into `jq -r` with the following filter, you should get the major versions, irrespective of how the version numbers are ordered in the curl results:

```
map(.name)
| map(split(".") | map(tonumber? // .) )
| group_by(.[0])
| map(sort)
| map( .[-1] | map(tostring) | join("."))
| .[]
```

### Variation

If you want the output sorted as well, simply remove the "v" beforehand, and then tack it on afterwards. In the interests of generality, let's define a function which will output the most recent release tag for each major release:

```
# Input: an array of "x.y.z..." strings, 
# some or all components of which may be integers
# Output: a stream of the latest "major" releases
def majors:
  map( split(".") | map(tonumber? // .))
  | group_by(.[0])
  | map(sort[-1])[]
  | map(tostring)
  | join(".") ;

map( .name[1:] ) | "v" + majors
```

### Typescript

```
$ jq -rf major-version.jq input.json
v8.11.2
v9.11.1
v10.1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You could pipe to this awk command:

```
awk -F. '!major[$1]++'
```

It uses the period as the field separator and prints every line of which it has never seen the first field, which is the major version.

In case the input is not sorted and you have GNU sort, you can use its version sort:

```
sort -rV | awk -F. '!major[$1]++'
```

where `-V` is for "version sort" and `-r` is for "reverse".

Comment: smart, it supposes the output from Github API are sorted already.

Comment: @Bill It does, as it seems to be the case. I'll add a sort step.